# If $n \mid a^2 $, what is the largest $m$ for which $m \mid a$?

Tags: divisibility, prime-factorization

Given $n$, what is the largest $m$
such that $m \mid a$ for all $a$ with $n \mid a^2$?

This is a generalization of
[if $40|a^2$ prove that $20|a$ when $a$ is an integer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1464583/if-40a2-prove-that-20a-when-a-is-an-integer)
where $n=40$
and $m=20$.

Here is my solution.

Let
$n = \prod p_i^{n_i}
$,
$m = \prod p_i^{m_i}
$,
and
$a
=\prod p_i^{a_i}
$.

$n | a^2$
means that
$n_i \le 2a_i
$
or
$a_i
\ge \lceil \frac{n_i}{2} \rceil 
$.

$m | a$
means that
$m_i \le a_i$.
If $m$ is as large as possible,
$m_i = a_i$,
so
$m_i 
=  \lceil \frac{n_i}{2} \rceil 
$.

If $n = 40$,
$n_i
=(3, 0, 1)
$,
so
$m_i
=(2, 0, 1)
$
and
$m = 2^2 5
= 20
$.

Possible generalizations:

(1) Let $j \ge 2$ be an integer.
Suppose
$n
\mid a^j
$,
What is the largest $m$
for which $m \mid a$?

(2) Let $j$ and $k$ be  integers
such that
$j > k \ge 1$.
Suppose
$n
\mid a^j
$.
What is the largest $m$
for which $m \mid a^k$?

Comment: The largest $m$ for which $m\mid a$ is always $a$ itself ...

Comment: Not the ceiling.  The ceiling is too big.  The floor.

Comment: @ fleablood: If the floor is used, you don't get $p^1$ in $m$ when $p^1$ is in $n$.

Comment: Okay, the wording needs work.  Might I suggest: what is the largest factor of n that divides a?  As written the n and the m have no relevence to each other and the largest m | a is, as Henning Makholm points out, is always m.

Comment: @HenningMakholm I think you mean $|a|$.

Comment: Presumably the intended question is: Given $n$, what is the largest $m$ such that $m\mid a$ whenever $n\mid a^2$?

Comment: That's still $|a|$, @Greg. Unless I'm missing something.

Comment: Presumably the question is this: "Fix $n$ and consider the collection $A_n=\{a : n \mid a^2\}$. What is $\mbox{GCD}(A_n)$?"

Comment: I think you are missing something (sorry), YoTengo - check the order of the quantifiers. The $m$ that is being asked for is well outside the scope of the $a$ quantifier, so $|a|$ (or any expression involving the variable $a$) cannot possibly be the right answer.