# Prove that for all integers $n$ if $3 \mid n^2$, then $3 \mid n$

Tags: proof-writing, solution-verification, proof-explanation

Prove that for all integers $n$ if $3$ | $n^2$, then $3$ | $n$.

I figured using contrapostive was the best method by using the definition "an integer $k$ is not divisible by 3 if and only if there exists an integer $k$ such that $n=3k+1$ or $n=3k+2$. Also using the definition $a$ divides $b$ written $a$|$b$ if $b=ac$ for some $c$ in integers.

Here it goes:

$$3\nmid n$$

$$3k+1=3n$$

$$\frac{3k+1}{3}=n$$

Comment: Use [Euclid's lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclid%27s_lemma), since $3$ is prime.

Comment: I assume Euclid's lemma hasn't be introduced yet.  As that would make this trivial.

Comment: Why does $3\not \mid n$ mean $3k + 1 = 3n$??????

Comment: Yes we have not gotten to Euclid's lemma. In a month we are covering that. For now the question is in the chapter of contrapositive and contradiction.

Comment: @John not even [Bézout's lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%C3%A9zout%27s_identity)?

Comment: @rtybase no not yet. It is only the first 2 weeks of this class

Comment: The reason I am asking is, you mentioned $n=3k+1$ or $n=3k+2$ so you are familiar with the [divisibility with remainder theorem](http://www.oxfordmathcenter.com/drupal7/node/113)?

Comment: I agree with rtybase... Just prove on with $n=3k+1$ or $n=3k+2$. (To write this way is just using the defn of divisibility)

Comment: More to the point.  If $3\not\mid n$ then $n \ne 3k$ for any $k$.  So $n = 3k + 1$ or $n = 3k + 2$.  (That's the remainder theorem).  So then $n^2 = ???$.  Obviously $3k + 1 = 3n$ *NEVER* happens for integers so ... anything you prove from this is doomed to be garbage.

Comment: I am *utterly* perplexed as to where the $3n$ came from at all.

Comment: @fleablood 
 "Also using the definition a divides b written a|b if b=ac for some c in integers." Is that not an applicable way to use that definition?

Comment: Write so $3|n^2$ means there exists a $k$ so that $n^2 = 3k$.  But how the #### did you conclude that there is a $k$ so that $3k + 1 = 3n$?

Comment: Would it be possible to just say $3\mid n^2\Rightarrow n^2\equiv0\pmod{3}\Rightarrow n^2-0^2\equiv0\pmod{3}\Rightarrow (n-0)(n+0)\equiv0\pmod{3}\Rightarrow$$n\equiv0\pmod{3}\Rightarrow 3\mid n$?

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to resort to proving the contrapositive; it's possible to prove the statement directly:

If we take as given that $3$ divides (exactly) one of the three consecutive numbers $n-1$, $n$, and $n+1$, then $3$ divides their product, $(n-1)n(n+1)=n^3-n$.  Now if $3$ divides $n^2$, then it also divides $n^3$, and thus it divides the difference, $n^3-(n^3-n)=n$.

Answer (score 1):

Presumably you have had the division theorem.

For $n$ and integer there exist integer $k, r$ so that $n = 3k + r$ where $0 \le r < 3$.  So $r = 0, 1$ or $2$.

Can you accept that?

If $r=0$ then $3|n$.

If $r = 1$ then $n^2 = (3k + 1)^2 = 9k^2 + 6k + 1 = 3(3k^2 + 2k) + 1$ and $3\not \mid n^2$ and that's a contradiction.

If $r = 2$ then $n^2= (3k + 2)^2 = 9k^2 + 12k + 4 = 3(k^2 + 4k+ 1) + 1$ and $3\not \mid n^2$ and that's a contradiction.

So if $3|n^2$ then the only possibility is $n = 3k$ for some $k$.

Answer (score 0):

I believe a simpler way is to use the unique factorization to show that for

$$n = \prod_{i \, = \, 1}^{m} p_i^{a_i} \tag{1}\label{eq1}$$

where the $p_i$ are unique primes, means that

$$n^2 = \prod_{i \, = \, 1}^{m} p_i^{2a_i} \tag{2}\label{eq2}$$

Thus, if $3 \; \vert \; n^2$, then one of the $p_i$ must be $3$, so $3 \; \vert \; n$.

Also, using your suggestion, if $n = 3k + 1$ or $n = 3k + 2$, then $n^2 = 9k^2 + 6k + 1$ or $n^2 = 9k^2 + 12k + 4$. In either case, when dividing by $3$, there is a remainder of $1$, showing that $3$ doesn't divide $n^2$. But, as $3 \; \vert \; n^2$, then $n$ cannot be either of the $2$ forms, so it must be $n = 3k$, giving that $3 \; \vert \;  n$. This is an example of proving what's requested using contrapositive as it shows that if $3 \not{\vert} \; n$, then $3 \not{\vert} \; n^2$.

Comment: Thanks for you comment. We have not gotten to unique factorization yet in mathematical reasoning class. Would my proof suffice?

Comment: @John I was editing my response when you wrote your comment. I hope it sufficiently answers your question.

Comment: @John Based on the definition for [contrapositive](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/contrapositive), I believe what I showed in the last paragraph uses the contrapositive technique. As for what you have in your question, as one of the comments state, I'm not sure how you get that $3k + 1 = 3n$, i.e., where does the "$3$" part come from in $3n$?

Answer (score 0):

In
[If $n \mid a^2 $, what is the largest $m$ for which $m \mid a$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1464864/if-n-mid-a2-what-is-the-largest-m-for-which-m-mid-a),
I prove this result:

Given 
$n = \prod p_i^{a_i}$,
then the largest $m$
such that
$m | a$ for all $a$
such that
$n | a^2$ is
$m = \prod p_i^{\lceil \frac{a_i}{2}\rceil}$.

If $n$ is a prime,
$3$ in this problems case,
then
$n = 3^1$
so
$m = 3^1$
also.